# Ruby Markdown / String Processing - Issue with Encoding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding, markdown

Good afternoon,

I am trying to use a javascript based editor (EpicEditor) to allow for admins on my site to input markdown for blog posts.  On clicking the submit button, the string generated by the editor is sent to the Ruby/Rails server for processing into HTML via RDiscount.

It mostly seems to be working, with the exception of something to do with `&nbsp;`, spaces and the like.  Clicking the "preview" button in EpicEditor is giving the exact output I expect, so I knew it was something to do with the way the string was being sent to the server.  I'm still fairly new to ruby, and not very good with string encodings etc.  I'm sure this is a fairly simple question for the right person.

To illustrate the issue - just showing the code is probably best.  I'm trying to input a bulleted list underneath an ordered list.  As such, the markdown would be something like:

`1. Hello

2. Goodbye

  - a list

  - entry

3.  For something`

My issue seems to be in and around the newline after the ordered list entry.  The string saved to the database, as well as what was in the javascript editor appeared exactly the same:
`"\n - had\n"`

However on further inspection, there was a slight difference between the "working string" (what was being used in the preview view in EpicEditor) and the "failing string" (the exact string stored in my database that had been passed by the form):

`working_string.each_byte {|c| puts c}

--> 10, 32, 32, 45, 32, 104, 97, 100, 10

failing_string.each_byte {|c| puts c}

--> 10, 194, 160, 32, 45, 32, 104, 97, 100, 10`

Somehow/someway, a `32` byte was being changed for `194 160`.  On further research, this appears to be some issue with a regular space in a string, vs. a `\xC2` or `\xA0`, and has something to do (I think) with `&nbsp;`'s.

Is there an easy way to make sure the string gets passed correctly going from EpicEditor to the rails server, and into the database?  I can also work with string substitutions on the server side if it will help....

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I went through and tried to find the exact issue.  I grabbed the text from Epiceditor, from the textarea I was mirroring from Epiceditor (to submit with the form), the params that went over the wire, and the string in the database.  The markdown was as follows (copied directly from the epiceditor text area:

```
## Testing this yet again

Because I want more!! More things to have a good time....

1.  Everywhere!
2.  Anywhere!
  - happy place
  - sad place
3.  Goodbye
```

If I paste this directly in to this input, you can see it properly renders:

### Testing this yet again

Because I want more!! More things to have a good time....

1. Everywhere!
2. Anywhere!

   - happy place
   - sad place
3. Goodbye

The ASCII characters of this string are as follows:

```
[35, 35, 32, 84, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 103, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 121, 101, 116, 32, 97, 103, 97, 105, 110, 10, 10, 66, 101, 99, 97, 117, 115, 101, 32, 73, 32, 119, 97, 110, 116, 32, 109, 111, 114, 101, 33, 33, 32, 77, 111, 114, 101, 32, 116, 104, 105, 110, 103, 115, 32, 116, 111, 32, 104, 97, 118, 101, 32, 97, 32, 103, 111, 111, 100, 32, 116, 105, 109, 101, 46, 46, 46, 46, 10, 10, 49, 46, 32, 32, 69, 118, 101, 114, 121, 119, 104, 101, 114, 101, 33, 10, 50, 46, 32, 32, 65, 110, 121, 119, 104, 101, 114, 101, 33, 10, 32, 32, 45, 32, 104, 97, 112, 112, 121, 32, 112, 108, 97, 99, 101, 10, 32, 32, 45, 32, 115, 97, 100, 32, 112, 108, 97, 99, 101, 10, 51, 46, 32, 32, 71, 111, 111, 100, 98, 121, 101]
```

I am copying the editor contents to a textarea via exportFile().  The ASCII characters in that textarea are as follows:

```
[35,35,32,84,101,115,116,105,110,103,32,116,104,105,115,32,121,101,116,32,97,103,97,105,110,10,10,66,101,99,97,117,115,101,32,73,32,119,97,110,116,32,109,111,114,101,33,33,32,77,111,114,101,32,116,104,105,110,103,115,32,116,111,32,104,97,118,101,32,97,32,103,111,111,100,32,116,105,109,101,46,46,46,46,10,10,49,46,32,160,69,118,101,114,121,119,104,101,114,101,33,10,50,46,32,160,65,110,121,119,104,101,114,101,33,10,160,32,45,32,104,97,112,112,121,32,112,108,97,99,101,10,160,32,45,32,115,97,100,32,112,108,97,99,101,10,51,46,32,160,71,111,111,100,98,121,101]
```

If you diff these arrays, I get the following:

```
textarea - epiceditor
 => [160, 160, 160, 160, 160]
```

In other words, there appears to be extra `&nbsp;` 's still being output from EpicEditor in the exportFile().  Any thoughts on where this might be coming from?  I complete the mirroring as follows:

```
var post_body = $("#post_body");
var content = post_body.val();

var editor = new EpicEditor(opts);

editor.on('load', function () {
  editor.importFile(window.location.href, content); //Imports a file when the user clicks this     button
}); 

editor.on('save', function () {
  post_body.val(editor.exportFile());
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

P.S. The following fixes the exportFile() output.  I'm happy that at the very least I've gotten it figured out, but I was hoping to get something that works natively with EpicEditor!

```
bad = "#{194.chr}#{160.chr}".force_encoding('utf-8')
good = 32.chr
self.body = body.gsub(bad, good)
```

Comment: There were `\r`'s in there before, but they weren't playing nicely with markdown so I "gsubbed" them out.  Could you explain a little bit more what you mean?  I'm not that good with this kind of thing yet...

Comment: Hey, I'm the creator of EpicEditor, there was a bug in 0.1.0 that would display `&nbsp;`s in the `exportFile` and also when you looked at localStorage. Fixed here: https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/issues/136 and it's fixed in the 0.1.1 release. Are you using 0.1.1?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  I'll check tonight when I get home and get back to you.

Comment: I am on the newest version of Epiceditor.  More details in the update

Comment: you can see the full details of each release as it progresses here: https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/wiki/Release-Notes -- is the latest (0.1.1) still not working for you? What does exportFile give you exactly? Can you repro on JSBin?

Comment: @OscarGodson Unfortunately 0.1.1 isn't working for me.  See the updates in the post up top (putting it in a comment wouldn't work so well!)  The exact contents of exportFile are in the update above - byte by byte.  Visually it looks exactly the same as text copied from the on-screen editor, but there are some extra `&nbsp;`'s in there.  To be 100% honest, I haven't used JSBin before.  I'll try to  get something going in there.

Comment: Using the chrome coffeescript console I was able to figure out this isn't a problem with EpicEditor..... the textarea and exportFile are NOT exporting nbsps.  Problem is when I submit the form, rails is URI encoding the form, and using nbsp's for spaces... I suppose I can just  yank out the nbsps on the server side?

Comment: Well, good it's not a bug with EE ;) bad it's a rails bug. Yes, I'd strip it out on the server side after getting the AJAX call.